# Silverlight Combobox Fire KeyDown event when combobox is open

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, silverlight, combobox

I have a Silverlight Combobox (happens to be in a StackPanel), with an event handler on the KeyDown event.  The handler only works when the ComboBox is closed, so it takes 2 clicks until it can be fired.

Is there a way to fire the KeyDown event or do the equivalent when the ComboBox is open?

Comment: The `ComboBox` opens a `Popup` with the scrolling content. This content is not in the same visual tree as the `ComboBox` so you will not get any bubbled events. I don't have an answer for you at the top of my head, but what you essentially need to do is get a reference to that `Popup` and add a KeyDown handler on the `Popup.Child` element.

Comment: short answer: no

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?
I would also suggest forgoing the event model and using binding for the selected item.

Comment: @Nkosi - I disagree, as my requirement is to act on a key press with an open Combobox.  That is what I need to do instead of the solution.  My solution suggestions include firing the KeyDown event in that state or an equivalent action that I can act on.  Not sure what you mean about binding, I do have the combo bound to its list and to the selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle `KeyUp/KeyDown` for `ItemsPresenter` within the `ComboBox`'s template. In my test, `KeyUp` gives a smoother transition, as compared to `KeyDown`.

[image]

---

**EDIT:** If you must keep your style in a separate dictionary, then you could do this:

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication5"
    x:Class="SilverlightApplication5.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <local:MyComboBox x:Name="cbx1" 
                      FontSize="24"
                      SelectedIndex="0"
                      Margin="0,0,10,0"
                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle1}">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Option 1"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Option 2"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Option 3"/>
            </local:MyComboBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt1" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="24"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=cbx1, Path=SelectedItem.Content}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MyComboBox:**

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyComboBox);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var itemsPresenter = GetTemplateChild("Ip1") as UIElement;

        if (itemsPresenter != null)
            itemsPresenter.KeyUp += ItemsPresenter_KeyUp;

    }

    private void ItemsPresenter_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedItem = e.OriginalSource;
    }
}
```

**Dictionary:**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication5"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationToolTipTemplate">
        <!-- Content removed due to a 30,000 character-limit per post. -->
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="local:MyComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2,25,2"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="comboToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#7FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#CCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay2"/>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#E5FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#BCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#6BFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay3"/>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight"/>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#E5FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#BCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#6BFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2"/>
                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundOverlay" Fill="#FF448DCA" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundOverlay2" Fill="#FF448DCA" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                </Rectangle>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundOverlay3" Fill="#FF448DCA" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient2" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                </Rectangle>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="Highlight" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" RadiusY="3.5" RadiusX="3.5" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentPresenterBorder">
                            <Grid>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownToggle" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource comboToggleStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="4" Margin="0,0,6,0" Stretch="Uniform" Width="8">
                                        <Path.Fill>
                                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BtnArrowColor" Color="#FF333333"/>
                                        </Path.Fill>
                                    </Path>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="White" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                    <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                                <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                                <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                            <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFE" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1">
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="Ip1" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: This looks promising, although I'm getting a silverlight parser error when I try to set a KeyDown or KeyUp on ItemsPresenter, so I'm trying to sort that out.

Comment: Please hit the **edit** button in my post and copy the corresponding XAML directly from there. Apparently there's a 30,000 character limit and it cut some of the presented XAML, but as far as I can tell, the full code I posted is actually still in there.

Comment: Setting up the key event is as simple as this: `<ItemsPresenter KeyUp="ItemsPresenter_KeyUp" />`. Look at the very end of the corresponding style.

Comment: That is the line thats throwing the parser error for me.  I've looked at the full code, doesn't look like I missed anything relavent.  I do have working controls and I'm trying to add the key press to it.

Comment: Do you have the corresponding code-behind for the handler as well? What exactly does the error say?

Comment: The handler is empty with a breakpoint atm.  The error is `Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2531    
Category: ParserError       
Message: Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.UIElement.KeyUp'.     
File:      
Line: 450     
Position: 59     
`

Comment: Handler is now like this:  `        public void ItemsPresenter_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = sender;
        }`

Comment: Name of the handler isn't important, I could call it MagicalRainbows and it would work the same.  I've tried various combinations of KeyUp/KeyDown, all with the same effect.

Comment: Any luck? Did you type-in the code for the handler or let the designer create it for you? In case you typed-in the code, I would suggest removing it from both XAML and code-behind, make sure it compiles and runs ok without that and then let the VS Designer create the handler for you. After it is all cleaned-up, 1) click on your `ItemsPresenter` in your XAML window; 2) select the **Properties** window and make sure it says **ItemsPresenter**;

Comment: 3) click on the event handler icon at the top-right corner of the window, scroll down to `KeyUp` event and double-click the text box for the event handler name. That's it, it should have been created for you, both in XAML and code-behind. Hopefully it will work...:O)

Comment: In the project I've inherited, there is no code behind here.  I'm trying to create.  On a related front, I've used your suggestion of hooking onto the ItemsPresenter to find the presenter programmatically and hook onto it, but that's not working entirely either.

Comment: I would create a separate sample project only to test this functionality, and once it is working and you're convinced of it, then try to figure out what the problem might be in the particular project you inherited.

Comment: I'm using Silverlight 5 and Visual Studio 2015. What about you?

Comment: I'm using the same silverlight and VS as you.  Could my problem be because the style is in a resource dictionary?

Comment: Only if the style cannot be found, I would assume... but hey... everything is possible when you don't know exactly where the problem is... I'll do some testing placing the style in a separate dictionary and report back.

Comment: YES ! That's precisely the problem. I get the very same **_Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.UIElement.KeyUp'_** if I move the style to a resource dictionary.

Comment: And that makes sense. You can't add event handlers in the context of a dictionary. If you follow my suggestion of having VS Designer create the event handler for you, it tells you right away: **_The document item has no code-behind file. Add a code-behind file and a class definition before adding event handlers_**.

Comment: Funny that we get that message though, as when I try to add code-behind it fails.  In any event, I was able to latch onto the ItemsPresenter programmatically, so you pointed me towards my solution in any case.

Comment: Glad everything worked out for you. Assuming you must keep your style in a dictionary, then I updated my answer accordingly. Unfortunately, due to a 30,000 character-limit per post I had to remove my previous answer. Cheers.

Comment: I didn't originally mark it because your solution is not really what I did to make it work, but upon review, it is a valid and best answer to the question as its worded.